# How to cast interface to a concrete type

Tags: typescript

I have the following:

```
export interface SimpleChanges {
    [propName: string]: SimpleChange;
}

export class PrivateComponent implements OnChanges {
    @Input() private text: string;

    ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
        console.log(changes.text.currentValue);
    }
}
```

The compiler gives me a warning:

```
console.log(changes.text.currentValue);
                    ^^^^
Error:(13, 29) TS2339:Property 'text' does not exist on type 'SimpleChanges'.
```

How to tell that the object will have this property and maybe a few others? I tried like this:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges as {text?:string, other?:string}): void {
```

but the syntax is off.

Also, as `@JBNizet` suggested, the following works:

```
console.log(changes['text'].currentValue);
```

why?

Comment: How about just `console.log(changes['text'].currentValue);`? BTW, `changes.text` is not a string. It's a SimpleChange.

Comment: @JBNizet, yeah, that works, thanks. I'll add that to the question)

Comment: @JBNizet, as I understand, `changes` is `SimpleChange`, not `changes.text`. Is it incorrect?

Comment: No. Read the signature: changes is of type `SimpleChanges`, with a final `s`. It's a Map where each key, of type string, as an associated value of type `SimpleChange`, without final `s`. If text was a string, how could you possibly do `changes.text.currentValue`? strings don't have any currentValue attribute.

Comment: @JBNizet, ah, yes, sorry, I misunderstood, you're absolutely right

Comment: @JBNizet, do you think [that](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9299) is related to my question? If so, it means that accessing indexable properties with `dot` accessor is not allowed in ts, correct?

Comment: Yes, it's the same "issue". But it's not an issue per se, just a misunderstanding of how TypeScript works. It's normal and expected to have to use changes['text'] and not changes.text, because there is no formal property named text in the interface SimpleChanges.

Comment: @JBNizet, thanks, I think you should put it as an answer. In JS it's the same, I was under impression that TS abides by the same syntax rule. But I understand what you're saying regarding the interface not having `text` property defined for it, only indexable properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TypeScript compiler will emit an error if you use `changes.text` because there is no formal property named `text` in the SimpleChanges class. It does that because the whole point of TypeScript is to bring type-safety to JavaScript, and spot potential errors in the code that JavaScript can't find.

To access the `text` property, you need to use `changes['text']`, which makes it clear to TypeScript that you know and accept that the property is a dynamic one, not formally defined in SimpleChange.